# SQL query to delete all abandoned tags from WordPress database

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

I used SQL query to delets more a 1K posts from my WordPress db. Now my db is left with thousands of tags not being used by any post.

Can someone plese help me with a SQL Query that will delete all tags from the tags table that has no post in the posts table?

Thanks You
Neeraj

Answer (score 4):

Something along the lines of:

```
delete  Tags
where   Id not in
        (
        select TagID
        from   Posts
        where  TagID is not null
        )
```

Could be more specific if you posted the table definitions.